# Receiving undefined method for acts_as_follower all_following and all_follows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently unable to list all users that a current_user is following or being followed by. I tried at least 6 different methods to get the Users_Controller to use the method(s) in the views.

The two methods/views causing problems will be placed below

```
 def following
    @user_following = User.all_following(:order => 'created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def followers
    @user_followers = User.all_follows(:order => 'created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Users Followers View

```
<% if @user_followers.any? %>
<% @user_followers.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to(image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user_path(user)) %>
    <%= user.username %>
    <%= user.followers_count %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Users Following View

```
<% if @user_following.any? %>
<% @user_following.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to(image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb), user_path(user)) %>
    <%= user.username %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Stacktrace error

```
Processing by UsersController#followers as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"john280"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `all_follows' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xd616898>):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in `followers'
```

Route.rb

```
resources :users, only: [:get, :show, :index, :edit, :update], path: '' do 
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
      get :followers
      get :following
    end
  end


/:id/follow(.:format)              follow_user_path
/:id/unfollow(.:format)            unfollow_user_path 
/:id/followers(.:format)           followers_user_path
/:id/following(.:format)           following_user_path
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `acts_as_follower` gem, it looks like `all_follows` is an instance method, but here you are calling it on the class. You'll need to find a particular `User` before calling `all_follows`.

Do you have a particular user to find the follows for? Or are you trying to find all follows in the database?

Since your route is a plural resource (with path set to ''), I'm assuming you're going to the page like `/123/follows`, so for instance your controller methods might look like this:

```
def user
  @user ||= User.find(params[:id])
end

def following
  @user_following = user.all_following(:order => 'created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def followers
  @user_followers = user.all_follows(:order => 'created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

If this is the case then your views shouldn't need to change.

Comment: Ah, OK -- I see, the `all_follows` method acts on an instance of `User`, not on the `User` class. You need a particular user to call the method on. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The method should already be exposed to the user. The follow/unfollow buttons are working correctly.

Comment: Is it just a matter of calling it on `user` not `User`?

Comment: Can you write out the complete solution please? for the users_controller.rb and followers.html.erb view.

Comment: Edited the answer w. an example.

Comment: Have you run your migrations?